# Ubuntu Gnome / Nvidia - Triple Monitor possible?

Tags: gnome, nvidia

Using default graphics it works fine without acceleration.  Installed nvidia-current and the second card won't run.

If I enable GPU-1 (210), even if GPU-0 (260) is still enabled it won't run and I go back to one monitor at 800x600.

I see there are hundreds of similar questions, but they cover everything from bumblebee to Unity/Compiz.  Haven't yet found anything applicable, advanced newbie when it comes to Linux.

Ubuntu Gnome, i5 3570k Desktop, Nvidia GTX 260 & GTX 210. 260 drives two 21.5" monitors at 1920x1080, 210 drives an old 17" monitor at 1024x768.

Comment: Did you try installing xorg-edgers PPA?

Comment: Most simple solution: Replace your IvyBridge setup with a Haswell-based setup that supports triple-head.